# What C++ HTTP frameworks are available?

Tags: c++, frameworks

What C++ HTTP frameworks are available that will help in adding HTTP/SOAP serving support to an application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, gSOAP of course. :)

http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html

Answer (score 6):

You could also look at:

http://pocoproject.org/

Comment: This is also nice piece of software. too bad i can't select more answers as accepted. upvoted though. thank you

Answer (score 2):

**NEW!** Answer to an old question:
Now there's Beast, which offers both HTTP and WebSocket:
https://github.com/vinniefalco/Beast
Here's a working program using the library:

```
#include <beast/http.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    // Normal boost::asio setup
    std::string const host = "boost.org";
    boost::asio::io_service ios;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver r(ios);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock(ios);
    boost::asio::connect(sock,
        r.resolve(boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query{host, "http"}));

    using namespace beast::http;

    // Send HTTP request using beast
    request<empty_body> req({method_t::http_get, "/", 11});
    req.headers.replace("Host", host + ":" + std::to_string(sock.remote_endpoint().port()));
    req.headers.replace("User-Agent", "Beast");
    write(sock, req);

    // Receive and print HTTP response using beast
    beast::streambuf sb;
    response<streambuf_body> resp;
    read(sock, sb, resp);
    std::cout << resp;
}
```

The documentation was recently updated too:
http://vinniefalco.github.io/beast/index.html

Answer (score 1):

[Yield](http://code.google.com/p/yield/updates/list) a high performance server framework, IIRC SOAP is supported.