# Download a URL in C++

Tags: c++, sockets

I want to be able to download a URL in C++.  Something as simple as:

```
std::string s;
s=download("http://www.example.com/myfile.html");
```

Ideally, this would include URLs like:

- ftp://example.com/myfile.dat
- file:///usr/home/myfile.dat
- https://example.com/myfile.html

I was using asio in Boost, but it didn't really seem to have the code for handling protocols like ftp and https.  Now I discovered QT has more what I need (http://doc.trolltech.com/2.3/network.html).

It's tempting to make the switch to Qt, but it seems a bit heavy and intersects a lot of Boost functionality.  Is it worth learning yet another API (Qt) or can Boost do more than I think?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Not a direct answer, but you might like to consider [libCURL](http://curl.haxx.se/), which is almost exactly what you describe.

There are sample applications [here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html), and in particular [this](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simple.html) demonstrates how simple usage can be.

Comment: +1 for libCURL.  It is built exactly for this.  It's more of a straight C binding (there's a C++ wrapper; haven't used it).

Comment: @Joe do you have an example (in C) compiled with MinGW for windows? I need this same example for windows using MinGW.

Comment: Updated the  link to "simple.c" which has moved.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [URLDownloadToFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms775123(v=vs.85)).

```
#include <Urlmon.h>
    HANDLE hr;
    hr=URLDownloadToFile(NULL, L"http://www.example.com/myfile.html",L"mylocalfile.html",BINDF_GETNEWESTVERSION,NULL);
```

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms775130(v=vs.85)), BINDF_GETNEWESTVERSION - is a "Value that indicates that the bind operation retrieves the newest version of the data or object available. In URL monikers, this flag maps to the WinInet flag, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, which forces a download of the requested resource".

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't go to Qt just for the networking stuff, since it's really not all that spectacular; there are a lot of missing pieces. I'd only switch if you need the GUI stuff, for which it is top notch.

libCURL is pretty simple to use and more robust than the Qt stuff.

Answer (score 2):

The [Poco Project](http://pocoproject.org) has classes for cross-platform HTTP and FTP (and a lot of other stuff).  There is overlap with boost.  I recently [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367984/what-c-http-frameworks-are-available/368145#368145) this, but have not used it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [URLDownloadToFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775123(VS.85).aspx) or [URLOpenBlockingStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775127(VS.85).aspx), although [cURL, libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/) are the proper tools for that kind of jobs.

Comment: Thanks for the mention of URLOpenBlockingStream! I couldn't find any good documentation on it anywhere besides rudimentary stuff on MSDN, but I finally figured it out (see my answer).

Comment: By the way, do you know the scope of what that supports, in terms of things like SSL, HTTP 2, cookies, sessions, and all that?

Comment: @Andrew, hi. The docs say that `URLOpenBlockingStream` requires IE3, so it probably supports the same stuff. For example, see [IE3 encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_3#Encryption). I don't think `URLOpenBlockingStream` supports cookies and sessions.

Comment: Haha IE3... But yeah, I kinda gathered that much from the documentation: the functions like `URL___` seem to be major abstractions of the rest of the "URL Monikers" API.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working without either libcurl nor WinSock: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51959694/1599699

Special thanks to [Nick Dandoulakis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1129253/1599699) for suggesting URLOpenBlockingStream! I like it.