# C++ download html file or get file contents

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Download a URL in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129194/download-a-url-in-c)

I want to either download/save a HTML file contents located on a remote server to local folder.

I just need the function if there is any.

Comment: There is no standard C++ function for this. If you tell us your technology stack, I'm sure someone can help you find a library.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a library I like: http://think-async.com/Urdl/