# Read .html file into string in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, file

I am looking for some tips how to read strings from a remote server over HTTP and save it into a string. Currently, I aim towards reading the first character.

@edit:
what I have already done:

I thought that curl might be the right tool to achieve that.

compilation:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: cURL, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  stdafx.cpp
1>  cURL.cpp
1>  cURL.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Lukasz\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\cURL\Debug\cURL.exe
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

but after debug:

```
The procedure entry point sasl_errdetail could not be located in the dynamic link library libsasl.dll
```

my main file.cpp:

```
// cURL.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"


#include <curl.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>


std::string buffer;

size_t curl_write( void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{
buffer.append((char*)ptr, size*nmemb);
return size*nmemb;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://google.com"); 
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, curl_write);
curl_easy_perform(curl);
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
fwrite( buffer.c_str(), buffer.length(), sizeof(char), stdout);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: A file on the local filesystem, or something served up over HTTP?

Comment: Ok.  And why don't you want to use CURL?

Comment: Just one char? Isn't that likely to be `<`? Or in any case not something that would map to `false`?

Comment: because first i worked with it for 5 hours and it won't work... at last when it suddenly has been compiled and i started debugging it show an eror with libsasl.dll and procedure sasl_errdetail or sth like that ;/

Comment: Post what you tried and the errors you got.

Comment: Or for something more modern, try `boost::asio`. There's an example of an HTTP client here : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/sync_client.cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem!!

downloaded  libsasl.dll from dlldll.com and getting same error. I assumed they have old version of dll so I downloaded newer version and it worked like a charm.

I got never version from http://theetrain.ca/tech/files/libsasl.dll

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the file.
2. Use the fgetc or istream::read functions.
3. Convert character to proper bool value.
4. Close the file.

HTML files can be read like text files.

Parsing an HTML file is another issue.

Answer (score 0):

Simply to receive html in a server/client setup requires that you connect to a socket and handle the messages that come over the socket.

Here is a well done example that introduces Sockets on Windows:

[Programming Windows TCP Sockets in C++ for the Beginner](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13071/Programming-Windows-TCP-Sockets-in-C-for-the-Begin)

If you want to completely avoid learning sockets and getting really good control of what is going on, you can use just a URL Downloader of sorts:

[Download a URL in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129194/download-a-url-in-c)

But using [URLOpenStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775129%28v=vs.85%29) will probably give you the fastest results, if you need speed over anything else.

So after you have a socket that receives the text of html, then you can parse the html and convert what you find into the appropriate variable.